# RTKQuery pass cross origin Request Header Session Cookie

Tags: reactjs, redux, cookies, react-redux

I am migrating a PHP page to React. Therefore I built a API in my backend that delivers the requested data as REST on a defined endpoint.

When called in Browser the API works as expected. When called from RTKQuery however, I am missing my PHPSession Cookie. I would like to keep the PHP Session for Auth for some time and therefore need a way to pass this using RTK Query.

I already set `credentials: 'include'` and `Access-control-allow-credentials: true` on the API side as well.

```
export const myApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'myApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://api.dev.myurl.de/v1/',
        credentials: 'include',
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getEntries: builder.query({
            query: () => 'getEntries',
        }),
    }),
});
```

Is there a way to pass the PHP Session Cookie directly as Cookie not using a workaround by sending its value via GET or POST or something.

**Edit:** The request is sent from another host than the actual destination URL. Neither the cookie of the request url nor the cookie of the destination URL is sent with the request headers.

The destination is set to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://request.host.de` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Comment: From this side, you are doing everything right. Take a look in Chrome's network request view - there you can see which cookies are available to a domain, and why they were sent (or not).

Comment: Thank you! I can see my session Cookie in the cookies section. 
 
On the Request Headers I can see that there are no cookies sent with the request and that I get a new PHP session Cookie with the response (which however is not set in the browser)

Comment: I am talking about the cookie section **within** the network request details. The cookies there should have different colors and information on why they are being sent or why not.

Comment: Yes and it says "no request cookies" although the PHPSESSID Cookie is set. As a response cookie I get a new PHPSESSID Cookie which is not persisted. I cannot see any information why the cookie is not sent with the request.

Comment: Ok, I figured out it actually does work if called from the same host name. If however called from a different host name it does neither provide these cookies set for the current hostname nor these cookies set for the destination hostname. Although the cookie itself was set for both hostnames